Under high concurrency, frequent timeouts occur when using fetch to pull resources in NodeJs
Now I have written a program like the following:
// NodeJs version: v20.16.0

async function fetchFile(url: string, timeout: number): Promise<Response> {
    const controller = new AbortController()
    const id = setTimeout(() => controller.abort('timeout: ' + url), timeout)
    return fetch(url, {signal: controller.signal})
        .finally(() => clearTimeout(id))
}

const testUrl = 'https://lf3-cdn-tos.bytecdntp.com/cdn/expire-1-M/KaTeX/0.15.2/contrib/copy-tex.min.js'
const count = 100
const timeout = 5000

async function test() {
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        try {
            await Promise.all(
                new Array(count).fill(testUrl).map(it => fetchFile(it, timeout))
            )
            console.log('success: ' + i)
        } catch (e: any) {
            console.error(`error[${i}]: ${e}`)
        }
    }
}

test()

When I run this code, frequent access timeout issues often occur, as shown in the image below.
console output
The probability of timeouts increases with the rise in concurrency, and I encountered similar issues when using node-fetch.
In this code, the same resource is being repeatedly accessed. In my actual project, I am accessing different resources concurrently, but I wrote it this way here for testing convenience. In actual testing, the resources that time out seem to be fixed; it's always a few specific links that time out. However, when I test these links individually, they all successfully fetch within 200 milliseconds (I set the timeout to 5 seconds). The timeout issue only occurs when multiple links are fetched simultaneously.
I want to know what causes this issue and if there is a way to ensure that timeouts do not occur due to high concurrency while maximizing the level of concurrency.

I had come across similar issues while working with our document management system while fetching files via our downloader utility.
You can try these solutions:

Limit the number of concurrent requests.

Implement retries and exponential backoffs for failed requests.

Consider using different libraries or tools that handle concurrency more effectively.

Monitor and adjust timeout settings and be aware of server limits.


npm p-limit library allows you to create a concurrency limit on promises. It’s useful when you need to limit the number of concurrent asynchronous operations.

So in reality, there isn't a precise method to determine an exact threshold, I can only estimate it myself, right?

yes you are right, you will have to use variable delay mechanisms like linear, or exponential backoff strategies.Based on any api rate limits whatever they might have.nd there is no exact idea of rate limits many times because of lack of documentation.
